# Why "Composite Layers" takes so much time?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm profiling list with infinite scrolling and data lazy-loading. What can cause this long "Composite Layers" phase?

[image: Screenshot1]

and

[image: Screensho2]

If you are interested in details about the list:

- The list has limited number of physical row elements and uses
  "transform: translate3d(...)" to reorder them when scrolling.
- Chrome paints each row in separate layer.
- There are just up to 25 layers in entire browser page.

Comment: If you have a link to the page you're debugging this would be super helpful. Kind of difficult to debug anything without seeing a webpage. From what I can gather from your post it seems that you have a bit of animation going on which could be the source of your problem.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual page but if you're constantly transforming as you scroll (as you described) then that would explain a large composite phase - transforms are carried out by the compositor thread with the help of the GPU. See: https://csstriggers.com/transform

Answer (score 2):

Without a link, it's hard to say for sure - but by the look of all the "purple" (in your first screenshot), you are likely using too many elements that contain any of the below properties:

A) have `position: fixed;`

B) are using `transform` before and during animations

C) using too many simultaneous `keyframes` (for example as you append rows while lazy loading)

Edit: Upgrade your version of Chrome - Performance replaces Timeline and provides a little more insight on the details you might be looking for.